# send a broadcast message to all items in list in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to send a broadcast message to all numbers returned from the `select` statement. It saves elements in the list but then it sends the same message to everyone. What am I doing wrong? Please see my method below.

```java
public static List<Message> listAllMessages(Connection connection) {

    List<Message> msg = new ArrayList<Message>();

    String messages = ReturnTexts.getMessage(connection, "EMPTYMESSAGE");

    String sql = "SELECT b.`productid` as productid, p.`productname` as productname, b.`msisdn` as msisdn , MAX(b.`amount`) as amount, b.`productcode` as productcode, a.`endDate` as enddate FROM "
            + TableNames.SAVEDBIDSTABLE
            + "b LEFT JOIN "
            + TableNames.PRODUCTTABLE1
            + " p ON  b.`productcode`= p.`code` "
            + " JOIN "
            + TableNames.AUCTIONTABLE1
            + " a"
            + " ON  b.`productcode`= a.`productcode` "
            + "GROUP BY msisdn, productcode ";

    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed() )
            connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        // LOGGER.info(sql);

        statement = DBConnection.isConnected(connection).prepareStatement(
                sql);
        // statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        long productid = 0;
        String productname = null;
        String msisdn = null;
        int amount = 0;
        String productcode = null;
        Date enddate = null;

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            productid = resultSet.getLong("productid");
            productname = resultSet.getString("productname");
            msisdn = resultSet.getString("msisdn");
            amount = resultSet.getInt("amount");
            productcode = resultSet.getString("productcode");
            enddate = resultSet.getTimestamp("enddate");

            msg.add(new Message(Long.valueOf(productid), productname,
                    msisdn, amount, productcode, String.valueOf(enddate)));
        }

        String messages = ReturnTexts
                .getMessage(connection, "BROADCAST")
                .replace("XXXX", productname)
                // .replace("YYYY", String.valueOf(amount))
                .replace("YYYY",
                        String.valueOf(maxBid(productcode, connection)))
                .replace("ZZZZ", String.valueOf(enddate));

        //LOGGER.info(messages.toString());
        try {
            for (Message obj : msg) {

                obj.setMessage(messages); 
                String apiUrl = "url/sendsms.jsp";
                getResponse(apiUrl + "?" + "user="
                        + URLEncoder.encode("xxx", "UTF-8")
                        + "&password="
                        + URLEncoder.encode("xxx", "UTF-8")
                        + "&mobiles=" + obj.getMsisdn() + "&sms="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(obj.getMessage(), "UTF-8"));

                //bulkMessagesLog(obj.getMsisdn(), obj.getMessage(),obj.getProductcode(), connection);
                bulkMessagesLog(productcode, msisdn, productname, connection); 

                //LOGGER.info(obj.getMsisdn() + " : " + obj.getProductcode()+ " : " + obj.getMessage()); 
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("UnsupportedEncodingException while trying to send SMS.");
            e.getMessage();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DBConnection.closeAllDBUsage(resultSet, statement, null);
    }

    return msg;
}


    public static void bulkMessagesLog(String msisdn, String message,String productcode,
        Connection connection) {

    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + TableNames.BULK_MESSAGESLOGTABLE
            + "(`msisdn`,`message`,`productcode`,`dateCreated`) VALUES(?,?,?,now()) ";
    try {
        if ( connection == null || connection.isClosed() ) 
            connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        statement = DBConnection.isConnected(connection).prepareStatement(
                sql);
        statement.setString(1, msisdn);
        statement.setString(2, message);
        statement.setString(3, productcode);

        //statement.addBatch();
        statement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        DBConnection.closeAllDBUsage(null, statement, connection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do iterate over the result set and build a list of messages in msg. Though you only create the text once, outside of the loop, so it's always the same with the (last) productname etc.

Should probably also be created in the loop.